# cURL STDERR is not working

Tags: php, curl, stderr

I'm currently writing a PHP class that takes in XML files exported by the firefox plugin tamperdata and lets you replay them in code with as much control as possible. This is basicly a cURL wrapper and the full source can be found here: https://github.com/tstrijdhorst/TamperCurl

My problem is that I cannot for the life of me get it to output STDERR to a file. I have done this plenty of times with cURL in other code and I never seemed to have any problems but right now it's simply not writing anything to the file.

This is where I initialize it:

```
    if($this->stderrLocation != null)
    {           
        $handle = fopen($this->stderrLocation,'a+');
        curl_setopt($this->curlSession, CURLOPT_STDERR, $handle);
        curl_setopt($this->curlSession, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 2); //Verbosity 2 to actually log something to STDERR...
    }
```

The instance variable stderrLocation is set by this function (and yes I checked with the debugger and it has the value I want it to have):

```
public function setOptions($options)
{
        foreach($options as $option => $value)
        {
            switch(strtolower($option))
            {
                case('cookiejarlocation'):
                    $this->setCookieJarLocation($value);
                    break;
                case('stderr'):
                    $this->setSTDERR($value);
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

The value is passed at the constructor like this:

```
    $tamperCurl = new TamperCurl('headers.xml',array('stderr' => '/home/shokora/stderr.txt', 'cookieJarLocation' => $this->cookieLocation));
```

When I look with a debugger it doesn't skip over the code, it actually goes into the function calls. Also the file exists and is even chmod 777 so there should be no problem with writing into that:

shokora@shokora ~ $ ls -la | grep stderr.txt

-rwxrwxrwx   1 shokora shokora          0 2012-05-04 13:22 stderr.txt

Does anybody have a clue what magic is at work here? This is really annoying me as I really need the STDERR output :r